# Configuring Nuget.Server to act as an Orchard CMS module feed

Tags: orchardcms-1.6, nuget-server

We need a private module feed for Orchard. I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to web services, but the problem we seem to be having is in the different schemas. I set up my remote feed as per Creating Remote Feeds:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

For this web service the schema is:

```
 <service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xml:base="http://localhost:57641/nuget/">
  <workspace>
   <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
   <collection href="Packages">
    <atom:title>Packages</atom:title>
   </collection>
  </workspace>
 </service>
```

Yet the Orchard schema contains a Screenshots element:

```
 <service xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xml:base="http://packages.orchardproject.net/FeedService.svc/">
  <workspace>
   <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
   <collection href="Packages">
    <atom:title>Packages</atom:title>
   </collection>
   <collection href="Screenshots">
    <atom:title>Screenshots</atom:title>
   </collection>
  </workspace>
 </service>
```

Is there a way I can configure the Nuget.Server web service to expose this too?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite non-trivial now, as the orchard gallery server and nuget server definitions parted ways somewhat. You can just about get it working by altering the Orchard gallery codebase (it expects several items that are not present in the data), but we abandoned our attempt in the end, as the complexity and altering the core code base was not worth the gain

Comment: Thanks Paul, we pretty much arrived at the same conclusion after a couple of days struggling with it and have shelved it for now. Bertrand indicated in this thread https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/448116 that it is something they need to look at, so hopefully it will get some attention in the near future.

Comment: At the Orchard conference they mentioned that the whole gallery concept was going to get some treatment, so fingers crossed